# Azure DevOps: wrong pipeline triggered by git commit

Tags: azure-devops

We have a project in Azure DevOps with two repos, let's call them OldRepo and NewRepo. NewRepo is a copy of OldRepo.

Both repos have a corresponding pipeline, OldPipeline and NewPipeline, each triggered when new code is committed to the corresponding repo. NewPipeline was created by exporting OldPipeline as json, importing it and modifying it.

OldPipeline works exactly as intended: you push code to OldRepo and OldPipeline starts up, pulling the job, getting the sources, etc.

The problem occurs when you push code to NewRepo. It triggers NewPipeline correctly, and NewPipeline runs without problem, but **pushing code to NewRepo also triggers OldPipeline**. OldPipeline fails at the Git Checkout step, as the commit hash from NewRepo isn't present in OldRepo.

I've gone through all setting I can find and even exported the build jobs as `.json` files and compared them, but everything looks correct with regards to triggers, repos and other settings.

Comment: are those UI build definitions? I assume they are. not sure how you even do something like that.

Comment: Yes, they were created through the UI. The weird thing is that everything looks on the up-and-up when looking at the UI build definitions.

Answer (score 0):

> It triggers NewPipeline correctly, and NewPipeline runs without problem

We can reasonably assume that the NewPipeline is configured correctly.

> but pushing code to NewRepo also triggers OldPipeline. OldPipeline fails at the Git Checkout step, as the commit hash from NewRepo isn't present in OldRepo.

Seems the OldPipeline can be triggered by the commit to the NewRepo, in this case, you will need to check the `Get sources` of the OldPipeline see if you choose the OldRepo as the `Repository` rather than the NewRepo.

[image]

Also please share us how you push code to NewRepo if above suggestion does not work for you. If you directly edit your code in NewRepo in Azure DevOps and commit, will the problem occurs? You can provide information as much as you think is necessary since the problem can not be reproduced according to current provided description.

Comment: Has this problem been solved? You can accept it as the answer if it helps. Or if you have checked the `Repository`, please share us the latest situation so that we can help solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. `Get Sources` for OldPipeline has indeed selected OldRepo, which is why it's extra confusing that it would choose to build when code is pushed to NewRepo.

Code is pushed using a regular `git push`. We've tested this from multiple computers with the same result.

Comment: What about push to your OldRepo using `git push` see if the OldPipeline could work normally and the NewPipeline will not get triggered?

Comment: OldPipeline works exactly as intended: you push code to OldRepo and OldPipeline starts up, pulling the job, getting the sources, etc. NewRepo is unaffected by this.

Comment: Sorry for long time reply. You said in your problem that the _NewRepo is a copy of OldRepo_, how did you copy from old to new one exactly?

Comment: If I recall correctly, we did it like this: 1) we copied the OldRepo folder to a new folder, where we changed files, namespaces, etc. We deleted the .git folder and created a new one 2) we created NewRepo in the project on Azure DevOps 3) we set NewRepo in Azure DO as the remote for the local repo and pushed the code 4) we cloned NewPipeline from OldPipeline and changed the relevant settings

Comment: This sounds complex. What about use the `Fork` which you can find in Azure DevOps - Repos, besides the `Clone` button(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxSj5.png) to create a NewRepo which is based on the OldRepo and do your `git push` see if the problem can be resolved.

Comment: I agree it looks complex, but it wasn't intended to be a fork, but a stand-alone repo, which is why it was done like this.

Comment: @YangShen-MSFT we have the same issue, of 13th of Jan everything was fine, on 14th we had no commits and on 15th the problem appeared. Both pipelines existed for 3-4 month before

Comment: Have you tried @local's solution? and has the problem been sovled?

Answer (score 0):

**Initial data:**

- Three Azure repositories with associated build pipelines: `A` `B` `C`.
- Pipeline `B` has been **cloned** from pipeline `A`.
- Pipeline `C` has been **cloned** from pipeline `B`.

All pipelines have been worked fine till January, 2020.

**Behavior:**

- Pushing code to `A` repo triggers pipelines `A` `B`;
- Pushing code to `B` repo triggers pipelines `B` `C`;
- Pushing code to `C` works as expected.

**Solution:**

After re-creating `B` `C` pipelines from scratch, all works as expected.